# How can I let browser cache static files?

Tags: python, browser-cache, web.py

Recently, I used web.py to build my application, and found that my static files were transfered in every request.

Below is my log:

```
10.18.40.100:49458 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap-responsive.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49461 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/bootstrap.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49461 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/mini.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/test_mini.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:45] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:52] "HTTP/1.1 GET /compeval" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:52] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49458 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:52] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/bootstrap.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:52] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49461 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:52] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap-responsive.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:53] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/mini.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:53] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/glyphicons-halflings.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:53] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /viewcompqlab" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49459 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49461 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap-responsive.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49460 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/bootstrap.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49458 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49458 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/mini.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49458 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:03:58] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49517 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:05] "HTTP/1.1 GET /compeval" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49517 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:05] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49519 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49518 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /css/bootstrap-responsive.css" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49520 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /js/bootstrap.js" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49520 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/baidu_mini.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49518 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /img/glyphicons-halflings.png" - 200 OK
10.18.40.100:49518 - - [19/Jun/2014 17:07:06] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 200 OK
```

Obviously, `.png`, `.ico`, `.css` and `.js` files are static and global valid in my server. So, my question is:
how can I avoid this and let browser to cache these static files unless pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Appendix, How do I serve static files in web.py, in my index.py file the code as below:

```
"""register serve"""
urls=('/', 'index',
    '/favicon.ico','favicon',
    '/(js|css|img)/(.*)', 'static')


"""def class to support serve"""
class static:
    def GET(self, media, fn):
        rmod="r"
        if fn.endswith(".png"):
            rmod="rb"
        f = open(media+'/'+fn, rmod)
        try:
            stream = f.read()
            return stream
        except:
            f.close()
            return '404 Not Found'

class favicon:
    def GET(self):
        f = open("static/favicon.ico", 'rb')                                                                                                                                                                                                
        return f.read()
```

Then in my template html file use these static file server:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Static files should not be served through `web.py`. Instead, you should configure your webserver to serve them on requests to the appropriate URLs - a common setup is to provide a `static` directory, where all static files reside.

Details on how to configure static files serving will vary depending on your webserver (apache, lighttpd, ...) and interfacing technology (fastCGI, mod_wsgi, ...). You can find common configurations on the *Deployment* section of [the cookbook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/)

Comment: No, web.py can serve static files. It's a simple application, so I just use web.py as my webserver. About how to pls reference: http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles

Comment: @eason I never said it *can't* - only it *shouldn't*. It's not a proper webserver, I think it doesn't have advanced features such as cache management. If it's such a simple application, why are you worried about caching, anyway?